# Implement SSO between Moodle and .Net C# solutions

Tags: c#, php, jquery, ajax, moodle

I'm quite new to Moodle and it's customization and integration with other solutions. I've been required to create a Single Sign On between an application we've developed in .Net C#. Username and password will be the same to. I thought to send the username and password to Moodle through Ajax.

This is the View code:

```
<div id="moodle">
    <input type="button" id="loginMoodle" value="Ir a Moodle"/>          
</div>
```

And this is my **JavaScript** code:

```
$("#loginMoodle").click(function (event) {                

  $.ajax({
    url: "localhost:8080/mymoodle/login/index.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: { username: 'myuser', password: 'xxxxxxxxx' },
    success: function () {
      alert('success');
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('error');
      alert(XMLHttpRequest.errorThrown);
      response = "err--" + XMLHttpRequest.status + " -- " + XMLHttpRequest.statusText;
      alert(response);
      alert(textStatus);
      alert(errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```

What I receive as the statusText attribute of XMLHttpRequest is:

> Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load
>   'localhost:8080/mymoodle/login/index.php'.

Any recommendations/guidance?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but aren't you missing the HTTP scheme part of the URL you're posting to?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using OpenID Connect and Thinktecture Identity server CORE.

This will allow you to support standard methods of authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's something I haven't tried before (& does actually work), wouldn't you need the 'scheme'/protocol included in the "url" value - aka 'http://' (?).